# How do I get this JSON data into HTML table like this using PHP

Tags: php, json

I already know how to connect to database and all that.  I just need to know what kind of PHP loop I need to get this data correctly

Here is the sample JSON:

```
[equipment] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 401582887101
                [name] => Driver Seat
                [equipmentType] => OTHER
                [availability] => STANDARD
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Number Of Driver Seat Manual Adjustments
                                [value] => 6
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Height Adjustable Driver Seat
                                [value] => height adjustable
                            )

                    )

            )
```

And here is what I want the table to look like:

```
id  name    equipmentType   availibility    attribute name  attribute value
```

401582887101    Driver Seat OTHER   STANDARD    Number of Driver Seat Manual Adjustments    6
401582887101    Driver Seat OTHER   STANDARD    Height Adjustable Driver Seat   height adjustable

Comment: your "sample JSON" is not json - not even close.

Comment: is that really so important?   I put it that way so you can easily see the way the data is structured.

Comment: well, if you *ask specifically* about a problem with JSON-data, then i asume it is important, otherwise you wouldn't have mentioned it. also, it's always a good sign to be precise, especially in coding, but also everywhere else. or would you trustingly eat a salad brought to you by a waiter with the announcement "here's your milkshake, sir"?   also, to your question: just about any loop would fit, but a `foreach` should be easiest.. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s a bit ugly code but it will work for your case, as long as the data structure of the array remains the same:

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<thead><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>equipmentType</th><th>availibility</th><th>attribute name</th><th>attribute value</th></thead>';
foreach ($data['equipment'] as $equipment) {
    $row = '<tr>';
    foreach($equipment as $key => $item) {
        if(is_array($item)) {
            foreach ($item as $attribute) {
                $attributeStr = '';
                $attributeStr .= '<td>'.$attribute['name'].'</td>';
                $attributeStr .= '<td>'.$attribute['value'].'</td>';
                echo $row.$attributeStr.'</tr>';
            }
        }
        else {
            $row .= '<td>'.$item.'</td>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```